# Method of characteristics- what do the characteristics tell you about the solution?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

Here  $u_0(\xi)$:=$u(\xi,0)$ where $x(0)=\xi$

It is clear from the picture that the characteristics go inwards towards $x=0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. I also understand that $u$ is constant on these curves. However, I do not understand why we can infer from this that the solution gets 'focussed' ( as displayed in the $u$-$x$ graph) around $x=0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-xt\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$;  $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$

$u(x,0)=u_0(x)$; $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$-te^-\frac{t^2}{2}\sqrt \pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is simpler than you think, since $X(t)=\xi e^{-t^2/2}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a physical analogy that doesn't depend on the fact that this problem is analytically tractable. Think of $u$ as a density of particles. Each particle moves along the characteristic that corresponds to its initial position, and the initial positions are distributed according to the initial density. Then the characteristic picture is telling you that all the particles are going towards $x=0$ as time goes on. This means the density of particles near $x=0$ is growing in time (since there are more particles near there).

Comment: In the graph of $u$ against $x$, $u$ does not change at $x=0$ for all time, i.e the density at $x=0$ does not increase

Comment: @usainlightning I said the density *near* $x=0$. The density at the single point $x=0$ really has no physical significance. That said there seems to be some loss of mass in this problem. I don't immediately see why there should be from what you've written. Could you write the equation?

Comment: I've added the equation to the OP.

Comment: @usainlightning Could you calculate $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x,t) dx$ and put it in the OP? (I could do it but I don't really want to.)

Comment: Have done underneath the equation

Comment: @usainlightning So you are indeed losing mass according to that formula. In my analogy, this means that what particles are surviving are going towards zero, but along the way many of them are being removed.